# Dependency Injection with WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

**Scenario:**

I created one solution with 2 projects. One is Web API project and another is class library for repositories.

I added ninject as DI into WebAPI project. This [blog](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/) well defined to use ninject with WebAPI.

I can configure repository Classes in RegisterServices methods in  NinjectWebCommon.cs file. This is available in app_start folder of Web api project.

**Clarification:**

I am confused that, now again i added reference of repository project to web api project to register dependency classes. Then how it is not seperate from repository project.

**Questions:**

Is this the correct way or i missed anything?

May i misunderstood the concept ? May be reflection to check runtime class find can avoid dependency

Please advise and give any correct blog or sample to explain this

Comment: You're configuring it in code. If you want true separation 1) define interfaces for what you wish to use, place them in their own project 2) reference this in both your website and your repository project 3) use a configuration file to configure autofac http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html this prevents the need to reference the repository from the website.

Comment: I think point 1 you mean seperate project for models. That fine. Point 2 is fine if model is seperate project. Point  3 is answer to my question correct. Ok so through configuration no need to add reference right? I didnt get any sample like that with web api. I will check that

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the 3rd project which is your bridge between your WebAPI and Repository library. Usually it contains your interfaces that your plugin DLL objects would implement and your WebAPI would use. All of your WebAPI code should be using interfaces as it is the job of DI to give you the correct class based on the configuration.

This is what allows you to swap out DLLs, add DLLs for new options, etc. The WebAPI project shouldn't reference the plugin because, well, you made a dependency on something you are trying to make dynamic.

Comment: You mean to create another library with ninject and refer all projects into that. So this new ninject library have all references and webapi have only ninject reference. Also interfaces are another library and it should refer to web api and also to ninject library. is my understanding right?